# Security error in firefox ext while fetching a file

Tags: javascript, file, firefox-addon-webextensions, local-files

While fetching a files contents with the following code in a background.js file:

```
function readFile(filename) {
    let response = fetch(`file:///${filename}`);
    console.log(response);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Security Error: Content at moz-extension://86d386b7-2904-441f-8dbe-47f0af9b6bfb/_generated_background_page.html may not load or link to file:///C:/Users/rando/Downloads/jest-26.6.1.zip.
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

My manifest file looks like this:

```
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "ws://*/*",
    "wss://*/*",
    "storage",
    "downloads",
    "sessions",
    "file://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "app/scripts/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

How do I solve this error and fetch the contents of the file using the background.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension access to local file system `file:///` has been blocked since Firefox 57 for security reasons.

Extensions can use the [input type="file"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) to launch the file picker on user-click.

Extensions also can:

- read files that are packed within the extension
- communicate with a software on the local computer via [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging)
- get files via HTTP/s, if the localhost has a server running

Comment: So, is there no way for me to read a file without user interaction?

Comment: youre wrong. a file list can be generated from both data transfer objects and clipboardevents see here https://github.com/fisker/create-file-list/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: I can't find any information about this being removed in Firefox 57. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @ban_javascript try [Bug 1215028](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215028), [Bug 1246236](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246236), [Bug 1266960](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1266960)